# PHPUnit gives error: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory] is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I created a simple test for my new Laravel 7 application. But when I run `php artisan test` I get the following error.

`Target [Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory] is not instantiable.`

The error doesn't appear when I go to the page in the browser.

```
$controller = new HomeController();
$request = Request::create('/', 'GET');
$response = $controller->home($request);
$this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you test endpoints in `Laravel`. You should let `Laravel` instantiate the application as it is already setup in the project, the examples you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php).

What you already wrote can be rewritten to something like this.

```
$response = $this->call('GET', route('home')); // insert the correct route

$response->assertOk(); // should be 200
```

For the test to work, you should extend the `TestCase.php`, that is located in your test folder.

Comment: But thats more a feature test than a unit test right? I'm pretty new to the world of automated tests. When should I use a feature test and when a unit test?

Comment: Yes, but you are trying to call a controller as a unit tests, that is not optimal as Laravel has tried to combat that, by emulating a "mocked" application that act as a real one. Unit tests in Laravel is testing single classes, that is out of scope from requests etc. I have seen multiple production systems with high test coverage and they all default to the feature tests approach, as it is very convenient. This is also described in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests. So safe your self some time and if you are new to this, just follow the documentation :)

Answer (score 6):

Although "*Just write [feature tests](https://laravel.com/docs/master/http-tests)*" may seem like a cop-out (*"They're not *unit* tests!"*), it is sound advice if you do not want to get bogged down by framework-specific knowledge.

You see, this is one of those problems that come from using facades, globals, or static methods. All sorts of things happen outside of your code (and thus your test code) in order for things to work.

### The problem

To understand what is going on, you first need to know how Laravel utilizes [Containers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container) and [Factories](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php) in order to glue things together.

Next, what happens is:

1. Your code (in `HomeController::home()` calls `view()` somewhere.
2. `view()` calls `app()` to get the factory that creates Views<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRQ16.png)</sup>
3. `app()` calls `Container::make`
4. `Container::make` calls `Container::resolve`<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRQ16.png)</sup>
5. `Container::resolve` decides the Factory needs to be built and calls `Container::build` to do so
6. Finally `Container::build` (using PHP's [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) figures out that `\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory` can not be Instantiated (as it is an interface) and triggers the error you see.

Or, if you're more of a visual thinker:

[image]

The reason that the error is triggered is that the framework expects the container to be configured so that a *concrete* class is known for abstracts (such as interfaces).

### The solution

So now we know what is going on, and we want to create a unit-test, what can we do?

One solution might seem to *not* use `view`. Just inject the View class yourself! But if you try to do this, you'll quickly find yourself going down a path that will lead to basically recreating loads of framework code in userland. So not such a good idea.

A better solution would be to mock `view()` (*Now it is really a unit!*). But that will still require recreating framework code, only, within the test code. Still not that good.<sup>[3]</sup>

The easiest thing is to simply configure the Container and tell it which class to use. At this point, you *could* even mock the View class!

Now, purists might complain that this is not "unit" enough, as your tests will still be calling "real" code outside of the code-under-test, but I disagree...

You are using a framework, so *use* the framework! If your code uses glue provided by the framework, it makes sense for the test to mirror this behavior. As long as you don't call non-glue code, you'll be fine!<sup>[4]</sup>

So, finally, to give you an idea of how this can be done, an example!

### The example

Lets say you have a controller that looks a bit like this:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends \Illuminate\Routing\Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        /* ... */

        return view('my.view');
    }
}
```

Then your test<sup>[5]</sup> might look thus:

```php
namespace Tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;

class HomeControllerTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testHome()
    {
        /*/ Arange /*/
        $mockFactory = $this->createMock(Factory::class);

        app()->instance(Factory::class, $mockFactory);

        /*/ Assert /*/
        $mockFactory->expects(self::once())
            ->method('make')
            ->with('my.view')
        ;

        /*/ Act /*/
        (new HomeController())->home();
    }
}
```

A more complex example would be to also create a mock View and have that be returned by the mock factory, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

### Footnotes

1. `app()` is asked for the interface `Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory`, it is not passed a *concrete* class name
2. The reason `Container::make` does nothing other than call another function is that the method name `make` is [defined by PSR-11](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/) and the Laravel container is PSR compliant.
3. Also, the Feature test logic provided by Laravel already does all of this for you...
4. Just don't forget to annotate the test with [`@uses`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html#uses) for the glue that is needed, to avoid warnings when PHPUnit is set to strict mode regarding "risky" tests.
5. Using a variation of [the "Arrange, Act, Assert" pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert)

Comment: Good info, but I do not agree with the test, first of all, it should be using `Tests\TestCase` and not `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`, as there is some setup also done (as you said, follow how the framework does it, see `FeatureTest.php`). Second, the test you provided is not correct as you are still setting up stuff that the framework already does. You can directly use `$response = $this->get('/url-to-test'); $response->assertViewIs('my.view');` and that will assert that the desired view is being shown... And third, never unit test the framework, only your own code... Feature test the whole !

Comment: For feature test I fully agree with using Tests\TestCase, but not for units. This is mostly to make 100% sure that any framework-specific dependencies are visible from the unit-test, instead of being hidden in the (abstract) parent case. That way I am 100% sure other developers won't be tempted to create non-unit tests.

Calling $response = $this->get('/url-to-test'); goes OUTSIDE the code-under-test, thus it is no longer an actual unit-test, which is what my answer tries to explain...

I guess I could _also_ add an example for a feature-test, but I feel that is already well documented. 

Comment: But, let me rephrase, if you want to know what view is being shown, you **must** do a feature test, I know you can unit test as you did, but that does not mean it is correct. You unit tests your own classes, not a framework class, that is what I meant. That is why I am saying this must be a feature test. Also, there is no other way of displaying that view (at least that part of the controller) through other way, just one route matches and will always do, so a feature test must be used here. What you have done is not good practice, if it was a job test, that would be bad.

Comment: What anyone should feature test: controllers, artisan commands, external API flows. What anyone should unit test: Job classes, your own code that does not follow any controller or command extension.

Comment: "You unit tests your own classes" Well, the controller _is_ one of my own classes!  But, to be serious... I think I understand what you mean. I'll give it some more thought and update my answer when I've got an idea how to clearly word the difference.

Comment: Yeah, if you are extending core, then it is not your class as literally yours alone, is part of the framework

Answer (score 2):

If you're finding this in The Future and you see @Pothcera's wall of text, here's what you need to know:

The ONLY reason he's doing any of that and the ONLY reason you're seeing this in the first place in a Unit test is because he and you haven't changed from `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` to `Tests\TestCase` in the test file. This exception doesn't exist when you extend the test case that includes `app()`.

My advice would be to simply extend the correct base test case and move on with your life.